# branch cut of $z^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

How does removing a ray at angle $\alpha$ from the domain of the function $$f(Z)=Z^\frac{1}{2}$$ makes it a analytic and single valued function.

Comment: Do you understand branches of the logarithm?

Comment: No.this is the first example of branch cut I came across.

Comment: You can have  a single value function using Riemann surface: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm -- it essentially amounts to preventing instances like $e^{4\pi i}=e^{2\pi i}=1$ (where in this example we might have removed the ray at angle $0^\circ$ because the logarithm would return two values.

Comment: No ..the main question is how did we make it continuous by removing a line from domain@EmilioNovati

Comment: @ShubhamUgare: $z^{1/2}=e^{(1/2)\log(z)}$.